# Unity of ring of cosets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have a set $A$ and $R=\mathcal P(A)$ - the set of all cosets of $A$. $R$ is a commutative ring with unity with the operations $ \oplus $ - the symmetric difference and intersection - $\cap$. $(R, \oplus, \cap)$

$\emptyset$ is the "zero" of $R$ and $A$ is the unity. For $X \in R$, I need to find the additive inverse of $X$ and which $X$'s will have multiplicative inverse.

$X\oplus X=\emptyset$, so I think that every element of $R$ is the additive inverse of itself (right?). But I am having hard time finding the multiplicative inverse. Which two $X,X' \in R$ will give me $X\cap X'=A$, except when it's $A\cap A$...

Comment: The multiplicative unity is $A$. So $X$ is invertible if there exists $Y$ such that $X\cap Y=A$. When can this happen? Note that the lhs is contained in $X$. So this entails $A\subseteq X$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove this is a ring or a field?

Comment: @julien, What is lhs?

Comment: lhs=left-hand side of a given expression. Here, $X\cap Y$.

Comment: @user69810 I only need the multiplicative inverse of $X \in R$. I already know that it is a ring.

Comment: I see. You are trying to classify which $X$s have multiplicative inverses. I would say @julien nailed it above.

Comment: Yes, thank you julien!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @julien said:

> When X∩Y=A $\Rightarrow$ A⊆X

but we also know that $X\in R \Rightarrow X\subseteq A$
which means that $X=A$

thanks once again!